# Prove principal ideal with no unit $\neq$ non-zero ring A.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let A be a non-zero commutative ring.  Let a ∈ A be an element which is not a unit. Prove that the principal ideal (a) is different from A .

Proof

$(a) = \left\{ a\cdot q  \ | \ q \in A\right\}$ and $\forall q \in A, \ a\cdot q \neq 1$. Thus $1 
\notin (a)$ , since A is a non-zero ring 1 $\in$ A.

$\therefore(a) \neq A$

Is it correct? Did I miss some assumptions? The proof seems a bit too simple. This is a 3rd semester Math undergrad exercise.
Thanks

Comment: Better: suppose that $(a)=A$. Then $1\in A=(a)$, a contradiction, because $1$ is a unit. Hence $A\neq (a)$. The proof really is simple, if not trivial.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  I think a proof of the contrapositive would flow better, but that's perhaps my bias against $\neq$.

Comment: I would say that $1\in A$ is true even if $A$ is the zero ring. The false satement in the zero ring would be $1\ne 0$.

Answer (score -1):

The only nitpick is that it could be more formal, by assuming that (a) = A and reaching a contradiction with a not being a unit, following the same chain of logic. But overall, it is correct.

Comment: I don't see how a proof by contradiction would be more formal than the current direct proof that $1\in A\setminus (a)$.

Comment: Oh well, you know, mathematicians like to complicate things, all for a greater purpose I guess.

Comment: @Saucy Typically, $a\neq b$ literally means $\lnot (a=b)$ (similarly for $a \not\in b$).  To prove that formally in logic, you might need to assume $a=b$ and then reach a contradiction.  In other words, while it seems "direct", such a proof would involve a proof by contradiction of every step, looking much like a chain of links rather than a straight line.